# Calculating resistance for variable voltage

Tags: voltage-divider

I have built a very primitive voltage booster with a push button.

[image]

Now I would like to add my ATMEGA328 to automate the switch. The problem I'm facing is that I want to measure the output voltage as well, but my ATMEGA's VREF is set to internal 1.1v.

I could make a simple voltage divider in parallel and take the reading from there, but I'm a bit confused about the following:

If my max output voltage is 20v, then my R1 value should be 190kΩ and R2 value should be 10kΩ, BUT what happens if my output voltage drops from 20v to 3v, wouldn't that cause R1 and R2 to try to 'draw out' more current from the capacitor? or is this the proper way of doing this?

The boost converter voltage will change from 0v to 20v in random phases, so basically what I'm trying to do is find a proper way to do this in circuit:

```
voltage_reading = voltage_from_capacitor / 20v;
```

Comment: It's certainly the simplest way. Don't worry about the current draw -- even at 20V you'll only draw 20V/200k = 0.1mA.

Comment: @calcium3000 thanks! what about if I wanted to boost it to 1,000v, that means it would try to draw 5A? what's the solution for this problem?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to boost it to 1000V with this topology, but you could still use a resistive divider.  You'd have to increase the resistor values of course.

Comment: great, thanks! you answered my question, you can post your comments as answer and I will mark it, thanks! P.S, how did you calculate the 0.1mA draw? thanks!

Comment: If I had known you would accept a answer so quickly, in well under an hour and while I was writing mine, I certainly wouldn't have bothered.  My bad.  I'll have to remember to avoid wasting time on your questions in the future.

Comment: @OlinLathrop sorry and thank you very much for your answer. I didn't know I should have waited as calcium3000 instantly gave me the answer almost instantly, I will wait longer next time, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly the simplest way. Don't worry about the current draw -- even at 20V you'll only draw 0.1mA:

\$ I_{FB,max} = V_{out,max}/R_{FB} = 20V/(10k\Omega + 190k\Omega) = 0.0001A \$

When V_out is 3V you'll draw even less current -- about 15uA.  This isn't much at all -- just the price we pay for feedback.

Answer (score 2):

First, a reference of only 1.1 V for the A/D in a microcontroller sounds quite low.  Check that, and also check what the A/D resolution is with such a low reference.

In any case, what you want is a *resistor divider*.  As you say, it's just two resistors:

[image]

OUT = (IN R2)/(R1 + R2)

If you want OUT = IN/20, then R1 must be 19x R2, as you say.

Note that since this divider has two resistors, there are two degrees of freedom.  So far you've only given us one criterion.

Possible second criteria are the impedance this must present to IN, or the impedance that OUT is being driven with.  The former is R1+R2, and the latter R1//R2.  For example using your R1 = 190 kΩ and R2 = 10 kΩ, the load on IN is 200k Ω and the output impedance is 9.5 kΩ.

The limiting factor in your case is probably the maximum allowed impedance the A/D needs to see its input driven with.  If the A/D can convert in a few µs and has more than 10 bit resolution, 9.5 kΩ is probably too high.

The other competing tradeoff is that the higher the impedence presented to IN, the less current is drawn and power wasted.  With 200 kΩ the divider will draw 100 µA at 20 V, which only uses up 2 mW.  That's quite small, and you won't be able to notice the resistors getting warm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you were considering using the Analog Comparator with the internal bandgap reference to give a simple "hi/low" indication, and using that to control your switch ...

If you want to have a variable output under software control, you would be better of using one of the ADC inputs.  Then use a divider to bring the voltage range of your circuit (0 ..20V) down to the range of 0 .. Vcc ( 3.3V or 5.0V depending on your application ) ...

One of the features of the ADC, is the ability to use the ADC to measure the "precision" voltage reference, to correct for the ACTUAL value of Vcc (see http://jeelabs.org/2012/05/04/measuring-vcc-via-the-bandgap/, inter alia)

You are correct -- there will be some loss associated with measuring the voltage in the output, it's inevitable.  Find a balance between losses in the voltage divider and noise performance that meets your mission needs.

Comment: oh sorry, I phrased myself wrong, I'm actually using the ADC to measure the level and output it on the OLED. The part I'm confused about is the extra 'draw' from resistors on the capacitor, when the voltage booster is producing voltage lower than 20v, thanks!

Comment: If the voltage booster is producing less than 20V, then the loss in the voltage divider will be proportionally less.  There is no "extra" draw.